# File Not Being Created in QT C++ using QFileDialog

Tags: c++, qt, widget

there I'm trying to make a simple notepad application. I've got a new file menu item. When the user clicks on that, it checks whether the text field is empty or not. If that is not empty then it prompts to save the work. If the user opts for yes then it asks for the location using QFileDialog. However, this code doesn't create the file at the provided destination. Can anyone figure out this code?

```cpp
if(this->checkTextField()==false){ //checkks whether the textField is empty or not
       QMessageBox::StandardButton reply = QMessageBox::question(this,this->appName,this->document_modified);
       if(reply == QMessageBox::Yes){
           QString filename = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this,"Save the File",QDir::homePath(),this->textFilter);
           QFile file(filename);
           QTextStream out(&file);
           QString text = ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
           out << text;
           file.flush();
           file.close();
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply creating a QFile will neither create nor open a file on the filesystem. You have to [open](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#open) it to write something to it/read from it.

Comment: Did the link wrong -> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qiodevice.html#open

Comment: If you make a mistake in your answer you can edit it to fix it. Answers that rely on external links aren't ideal as when the link inevitably breaks your answer becomes useless, you should add a little more explanation and maybe a code example.

Comment: I was unable to edit it - maybe not enough reputation? I think the link should be very stable since when it's dead then Qt is dead too but here a small example from the documentation:

    QFile file("out.txt");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text))
        return;
    QTextStream out(&file);
    out << "The magic number is: " << 49 << "\n";
    file.close();

The formatting options are crappy... :(

Comment: you should always be able to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70936119/edit) your own post and your example should be edited into it rather than being in the comments where the formatting breaks. Qt have moved their documentation around a few times over the years and there is no guarantee they won't do it again and break your link